# Which account is the top level user account in Windows 7?

Tags: windows

In Windows 7, which account is higher than the administrator account?

In addition, how we can turn off the pop up dialog boxes which ask for admin permission to run, causing the whole screen to go off for 0.5 seconds?

Comment: If you don't know how to disable the UAC, you don't need access to the SYSTEM account.. if that's even possible to get on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable UAC to prevent the popup. Additionally , SYSTEM account has higher privileges than Administrator account in Windows in the sense that many system level modifications can only be done through SYSTEM account like making system calls, memory management ,etc. You will need administrator rights but essentially they will run under the context of SYSTEM account.

Comment: how to disable UAC and How to create SYSTEM account please tell steps

Comment: Ugh... don't do that, seriously. UAC is admittedly annoying (but mostly because application developers are stupid -- they still don't get it that 99% of all programs do not really need admin rights -- not because of Windows). However, it is nevertheless something you want to keep enabled at all times. You _really do not want to_ give every program root access to your computer (and probably don't want to execute a program that "needs" admin rights for no obvious reason at all).

Comment: @user1553435 To turn off UAC simply type in command line:   `C:\Windows\System32\UserAccountControlSettings.exe` and drag controll to "Never Notify". And you cannot create SYSTEM account, you can only achieve SYSTEM privileges using another account.